# Merging a Layer with Input in Keras without Functional API

Tags: merge, concatenation, keras, theano, sequential

With Keras it is possible to merge two Sequential instances just with the "model.add()"-approach, without using the Functional API.

E.g.:

```
from keras.layers import Merge

left_branch = Sequential()
left_branch.add(Dense(32, input_dim=784))

right_branch = Sequential()
right_branch.add(Dense(32, input_dim=784))

merged = Merge([left_branch, right_branch], mode='concat')
```

Example taken from: [Keras Sequential Model Guide](https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/1.0.0/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/)

Now, there are various examples how to merge/concatenate a Layer with raw inputs (no dense layer like in the example above), but all examples are with Functional API.

**What is the correct syntax (if available) to use "Merge" like this?**

```
from keras.layers import Merge

left_branch = Sequential()
left_branch.add(Dense(32, input_dim=784))

right_branch = Input(input_dim=784)

merged = Merge([left_branch, right_branch], mode='concat')
```

Comment: There is no reason to avoid using the functional API.